# ContextMenu Items in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, contextmenu, jstree

I want to show conditional contextMenu Items via jQuery.

For Example :

I have cars in my account. And I wanted to show options on conditions.

If car is of my own then all menu items should be visible to me. And if it is shared with me then only View Menu should to visible to me.

```
if (type == 'vehicle') {
   (function () {
     var vehicle_id = node.data.vehicle_id;
     var vehicle_status = '';
     $.ajax({
        url: baseUrl + '/check-vehicle-status/'+vehicle_id,
                        success: function(data) {
                            console.log(data);
                            if(data == 'shared'){
                                //what should I write here? to show only View option 
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    items = {
                        "View": {
                            "label": "View Vehicle", 
                            "action": function action() {
                                self.viewVehicle(vehicle_id);
                            }
                        },
                        "modify": {
                            "label": "Edit Vehicle", 
                            "action": function action() {
                                self.editVehicle(vehicle_id);
                            }
                        },
                        "delete": {
                            "label": "Delete Vehicle",
                            "action": function action() {
                                dialogHandler.showDeleteVehicle(function () {
                                    self.removeVehicle(vehicle_id);
                                });
                            }
                        },
```

Comment: Please share what you already have

Comment: I am sending ajax call with car ID which gives me car is my own or shared with me. soo I want to add this condition if car is shared with me show only View oprion. Other wise show all options likes EDIT,DELETE, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to check the `data` param in the context menu method like below (provided that the `node.data` of a tree node will have a value).

Check demo - [Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/u8vqpeux/)

```
...
contextmenu: {
  items: function (node) { 

      // remove default context menu items
      var tmp = $.jstree.defaults.contextmenu.items();
      delete tmp.rename;
      delete tmp.remove;
      delete tmp.ccp;
      delete tmp.create;

      for (menuItem in items) {
         if( menuItem === 'View' || node.data !== 'shared') { 
              tmp[ menuItem ] = {
                 id: menuItem,
                 label: items[menuItem].label,
                 action: items[menuItem].action
              }
          }
      }

      return tmp;
  }
},
```

Comment: Hey Thank Nikolay for your response. But can you help to make ajax response global so that I can use that in items

Comment: Sure, but I afraid I didn't get the idea. Do you want to make an ajax call when a node is right-click and before showing context menu?

Comment: Yes. According to ajax call result, Menu subitems should display.